# Error: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

Tags: go, terraform, grpc, digital-ocean

I am using grpc go lang . and with that transformer . Don't know suddenly this error start appearing and no data is receiving on front end . Can any one please guide what is this error about ?

**My log file** :

```
2021/05/07 21:52:10 INFO: /api.VehicleService/GetVehicle
2021/05/07 21:52:10 ERROR: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2021/05/07 21:52:10 ERROR: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2021/05/07 21:52:10 ERROR: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
```

and kindly let me know which file I need to paste here to get proper guideline. as I am new in this .

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your log it seems that a context is canceled. The reason might because your client is canceling the context of the request.
Please provide your client and also your server code, I believe that will help us to help you.
Creating connection in client and method of server that  this error happens inside of it.

Comment: thanks for answer , Are you saying that issue is on front end side ?

Comment: you mean   GetVehicle()   function code ?

Comment: I can't say this certainly that the front-end has an error. But I am sure that something is cancelling the request context. At first, check the front-end and debug it to see what is happening. if there is no problem, provide your code that is invoked to find the problem.